# Extract addresses separated by semicolon and print each address in a line

Tags: grep, regular-expression, string, search, text-formatting

I have a file with the following input. The numbers separated by dots represents addresses. Any number in address can be one or more digits as follows:

```
[112.112.112.112;3.3.3.3;44.44.44.44]
[6.6.6.6;17.17.17.17;88.88.88.88]
```

I want to extract each address without the semicolons and brackets (addresses are separated by semicolon `;`), and insert each address in a line in a new file to produce this output:

```
112.112.112.112
3.3.3.3
44.44.44.44
6.6.6.6
17.17.17.17
88.88.88.88
```

As a first step, I tried grep to extract the addresses as follows:

```
grep -E '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

But it does not print anything.

Comment: Should 'output to contains only unique umbers and no duplicates' read 'output to contain only unique addresses (i.e. no duplicates)'?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. But that is obvious now to pipe with and sort using: `| sort -u`. I will remove it form the questions though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Extended Regex** (`-E` or `egrep`) does not know about `\d`. Use `-P` as suggested by @Alexander or use `-E` with `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Add `-o` to select the matches only instead of whole matching lines. This will also break up the single matches into new lines.

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' myfile.txt
```

or

```
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+' myfile.txt
```

---

using **Perl Regex** (`-P` or `pgrep`):

```
grep -Po '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' myfile.txt
```

---

If you change `+` to `*` you can also use **Basic Regex**:

```
grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' myfile.txt
```

Comment: I liked this answer as it expalined what's -o for and why -E does not work. But I will use `grep -P -o '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' myfile.txt` as it is more readable. So can you add it so I accept the answer please?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `-E` with `-P` and add `-o`:

```
 grep -P -o '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NF' RS='[][;]' infile
```

Or with `tr` if you don't mind the first empty line:

```
tr -s '];[' '\n' <infile
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is kind of overkill for this task. `tr` is sufficient:

```
$ < input.txt tr -d '[]' | tr ';' '\n' | sort -u
```

The `sort -u` part removes duplicate addresses.